# Error connecting to Quickbooks Desktop POS through the web connector

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I have a client that needs to connect his website to the Quickbooks Desktop POS 18.0. I Downloaded the Quickbooks webconnector, but the latest version gives an error and says I need quickbooks 2015 or later, so I downloaded the 2.1.0.30 version and was able to install it on the machine.

I then used the following php application https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php. I installed it on my server, got the ssl certificate and everything needed for security. I'm only using it for tests now, but the problem is that when I generate the .qwc file and use it on the web connector I get the following error: Error QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector Could not verify the web application server certificate.

The domain I use is https://filcp.com/

[Here is the certificate for the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuxLc.png)

This is how my qwc file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
    <AppName>My QuickBooks SOAP Server</AppName>
    <AppID></AppID>
    <AppURL>https://filcp.com/QuickBooks/SOAP/Server.php</AppURL>
    <AppDescription>An example QuickBooks SOAP Server</AppDescription>
    <AppSupport>https://filcp.com</AppSupport>
    <UserName>userName</UserName>
    <OwnerID>{57F3JK78-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-9H64VB813D20}</OwnerID>
    <FileID>{57F3JK78-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-9H64VB813D20}</FileID>
    <QBType>QBPOS</QBType>
    <Notify>false</Notify>
    <Scheduler>
        <RunEveryNMinutes>10</RunEveryNMinutes>
    </Scheduler>
    <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

I followed many tutorials about configuring ie and all, but nothing has worked so far. I can access the application through ie, but I still get that error on the web connector.

Can someone help me to figure out what may be causing it and if there is any other way that I can connect the client's website to Quickbooks POS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit the URL you're referencing in the `.QWC` file:

- https://filcp.com/QuickBooks/SOAP/Server.php

You can clearly see that you're getting back a response of:

`500 Internal Server Error`

Your code is broken. Fix your code. If you need further hope, post your code so we can help you. Also, post your logs from the Web Connector (hit the `View Log` button).

Comment: I was doing it all wrong. Thanks Keith, you have certainly pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. I worked on using the Example App Web Connector. My .QWC file is now referencing to this url, https://www.filcp.com/docs/example_app_web_connector/qbwc.php which is working fine now, but I'm still getting the same error. Error QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector Could not verify the web application server certificate. DO you think it could be because the quickbbooks and web connector version is too old? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should post your logs so we can actually help you.